# Implement the Drag&Drop for sidebar menu

Tags: javascript, css, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have 2 vertical div: left and central panel.

I use the left div like a sidebar menu and I would like to implement a drag&drop to move the left sidebar to a new right sidebar (to move the menu from left to right side).

When the user start to drag, I would like to show where is possible to drop the panel (so I need to show a right empty sidebar) and when the user drop the panel from left to the right destination I need to hide the left panel. Same situation when the user start to drag from right to left panel.

I have see some possible ways to implement this using jQuery UI or directly DnD integrated of HTML5 ([example](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/#toc-examples)).

Do you know which one is the best solution (also as speed of implementation of it)?

I think that to get exactly what I want (also with the show/hide of the three panels), I need to write some code.. Do you know any tutorial / example very close to what I would like to do?

Comment: This is not a complete example. If you are sinmply going to hide/unhide sidebars when the user switches, I would have both available, but 1 hidden. When dragging is happening, you can then create a ghost target or unhide both with opacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with animation: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/jf6urpep/

As you did not provide an example of the HTML, script, or concept, I created a basic example.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Sidebar Left -->
<div class="sidebar-l" style="height:100%; position: relative;">
  <div class="w3-sidebar w3-light-grey w3-bar-block" style="width:25%; position: absolute;">
    <h3 class="w3-bar-item">Menu</h3>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Sidebar Right -->
<div class="sidebar-r" style="margin-left: 75%; width:0; height:100%; position: relative;">
</div>
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="content" style="margin-left:25%">
  <div class="w3-container w3-teal">
    <h1>My Page</h1>
  </div>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_car.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-container">
    <h2>Sidebar Navigation Example</h2>
    <p>The sidebar with is set with "style="width:25%".</p>
    <p>The left margin of the page content is set to the same value.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(".w3-sidebar").draggable({
    handle: "h3.w3-bar-item",
    drag: function(e, ui) {
      if (ui.position.left > $(window).width() / 2) {
        $(".sidebar-l").css({
          "width": 0
        });
        $(".sidebar-r").css({
          "width": "25%"
        });
        $(".content").css({
          "margin-left": 0,
          "margin-right": "25%"
        });
      } else {
        $(".sidebar-l").css({
          "width": "25%"
        });
        $(".sidebar-r").css({
          "width": 0
        });
        $(".content").css({
          "margin-left": "25%",
          "margin-right": 0
        });
      }
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      var side, pos, center;
      pos = ui.position;
      center = $(window).width() / 2;
      console.log(pos, center);
      if (pos.left > center) {
        side = "r";
      } else {
        side = "l";
      }
      console.log("target", side);
      var sidebar = $(".w3-sidebar").detach();
      console.log("detach", sidebar);
      sidebar.appendTo($(".sidebar-" + side)).position({
        my: "left top",
        at: "left top",
        of: $(".sidebar-" + side),
        using: function(css, calc) {
          $(this).animate(css, "fast");
        }
      })
      console.log("append to", $(".sidebar-" + side));
    }
  });
  $("h3.w3-bar-item").disableSelection();
});
```

Depending on where the item is dragged, we swap which side has the margin space. This helps indicate to the user where the sidebar will land. The user can basically drop the sidebar on either side and it will snap to position.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Psuedo code based on your example link:

1. Put both sidebar elements in your HTML as `sidebar sidebar--left` and `sidebar sidebar--right`
2. Fill one with the actual sidebar content.
3. Add the class `sidebar--hidden` to the other. Style that to hide the element.
4. On `dragstart`, remove the class `sidebar--hidden` and add a class to both sidebars like `sidebar--droppable`. Style them appropriately
5. On `drop`, remove `sidebar--droppable` from both and add `sidebar--hidden` to the other
6. Don't forget to accommodate for drops that do not fall on a sidebar drop target. You can use `dragend` for that case and just put it back to where it started (or maybe test the position and if >50%, make it a right sidebar...)

Though, if this is really just a choice between left and right sidebars, probably easier to have a button/checkbox type control on the sidebar and simply move it in the DOM when toggled (and on page load via some persistence mechanism). Or have both sidebars in the DOM and move the `innerHTML`. If you don't use padding or borders on the sidebars elements themselves they should collapse to hidden when they have no content.